# How to get the rows corresponding to a plot selection in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a bar graph which is part of a shiny app. I have created it with plotly. I would like the user to be able to select a part of the graph (click) and on clicking a datatable would show all rows corresponding to the values given in the hover text from that part of the chart.

So far I am able to show the output from event.data which isnt very interesting. How can I show the relevant rows from the original table?

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ChooserDropdown"),
  plotlyOutput("plot2"),

  DT::dataTableOutput("tblpolypDetail2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
    #key <- row.names(mtcars)
browser()
      p <- ggplot(iris,aes_string(iris$Species,input$Chooser)) + geom_col()
      ggplotly(p,source = "subset") %>% layout(dragmode = "select")

  })
  output$tblpolypDetail2 <- renderDataTable({
    event.data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "subset")
    print(event.data)
  })


output$ChooserDropdown<-renderUI({
  selectInput("Chooser", label = h4("Choose the endoscopic documentation column"),
              choices = colnames(iris) ,selected = 1
  )
})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a small demo where you can highlight rows in datatable by clicking the plotly graph.

---

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Map `pointNumber` of a click to rows in datatable(), you can create an external table for it.
2. You need to create a `dataTableProxy` where you can update a datatable

```
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data <- as_tibble(iris) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>%
    mutate(Species = as.character(Species))

species_mapping <- data.frame(
    Species = data$Species,
    row_id = 1:length(data$Species),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
         p <- data %>%
            ggplot() +
            geom_col(aes(x = Species, y = avg))
         # register this plotly object
         plotly_object <- ggplotly(p,source = "source1")
         event_register(plotly_object,event = "plotly_click")
         plotly_object

    })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data)

    # create a proxy where we can update datatable
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("table")

    observe({
        s <- event_data("plotly_click",source = "source1")
        req(!is.null(s))
        # map point number to Species
        row_clicked <- species_mapping[s$pointNumber + 1,"row_id"]
        proxy %>%
            selectRows(NULL) %>%
            selectRows(row_clicked)

    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @YifuYan. I would like the table shown to be the original iris table (rather than grouped by species) so that all rows (for example with setosa) are shown.

Comment: Also I dont understand why I can't have access to the same variables that the hover text has access to rather than refer to pointNumber...

Comment: I did the grouped table just for simplicity. You can map to the original table by changing the mapping table.